# Proxy HTTPS never receives data from either client or server

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, proxy, http-proxy

My proxy HTTPS, dealing with `CONNECT` HTTP requests from client, does the following steps:

1. opens a socket to remote server;
2. sets the socket to non blocking mode;
3. attempts `connect()` checking for `if ((connect_res == -1) && (errno != EINPROGRESS))`;
4. loops with `select()` checking if server socket is ready to send or receive data;
5. sets socket back to blocking mode;
6. sends `"HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n"`to the client after successfull `connect()`;
7. calls `proxyHTTPS()`;

   ```
   // if client sent a CONNECT request...
   struct sockaddr_in remote_server, local_bind;
   int conn_res, select_res;

   memset(&remote_server, 0, sizeof(remote_server));
   remote_server.sin_family = AF_INET;
   remote_server.sin_addr.s_addr = rm.getServerAddr();
   remote_server.sin_port = rm.getServerPort();

   memset(&local_bind, 0, sizeof(local_bind));
   local_bind.sin_family = AF_INET;
   local_bind.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   local_bind.sin_port = htons(0);

   fd_set rdset, wrset;
   struct timeval tv;

   sockfd_server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
   if (sockfd_server < 0) {
       perror("socket: ");
   }

   // make socket not blocking
   if(!setNonBlocking(sockfd_server))
       perror("fcntl");
   debug_green("CONNECT set socket to non-blocking mode\n");

   bind(sockfd_server, (struct sockaddr*) &local_bind, sizeof(local_bind));

   conn_res = connect(sockfd_server, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
   // The socket is nonblocking and the connection cannot be completed immediately
   // check for EINPROGRESS
   if ((conn_res == -1) && (errno != EINPROGRESS)) {
       debug_yellow("CONNECT attempting select()\n");
       do {
           FD_ZERO(&rdset);
           FD_SET(sockfd_server, &rdset);
           wrset = rdset;
           tv.tv_sec = 0;
           tv.tv_usec = 0;
           select_res = select(sockfd_server+1, &rdset, &wrset, NULL, &tv);
       } while ((select_res == -1) && (errno == EINTR));

       if ((!FD_ISSET(sockfd_server, &rdset)) && ((!FD_ISSET(sockfd_server, &wrset)))) {
           debug_red("SELECT sockfd non risponde\n");
           close(sockfd_server);
           sockfd_server = -1;
           return false;
       }

       /* repeat not blocking connect() to check if it gives error saying connection already happened (from my teacher's slides) */
       conn_res = connect(sockfd_server, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
       if (conn_res == -1)  {
           if(errno == EISCONN)
               printf ("connect(): connection already existing, OK\n");
           else  {
               printf("connect(): connection failed\n");
               close(sockfd_server);
               sockfd_server = -1;
               return false;
           }
       }
       printf("connection OK\n");
   } else {
       debug_green("connected immediately\n");
   }
   if (!setBlocking(sockfd_server)) {
       perror("FCNTL:");
   }
   debug_green("CONNECT set socket back to blocking mode\n");fflush(stdout);
   // #define CONNECT_200_OK HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n
   std::string connect_200_to_client(CONNECT_200_OK);
   int connect_200_to_client_send = send(new_sockfd_client, connect_200_to_client.c_str(), sizeof(connect_200_to_client), 0);
   if (connect_200_to_client_send <= 0) {  
       perror("CONNECT send() 200 OK to client failed");
       close(sockfd_server);
       sockfd_server = -1;
       return false;
   }
   // finally calling proxyHTTPS
   hm.proxyHTTPS(new_sockfd_client, sockfd_server);
   ```

Now I should be ready to forward data from client to server and from server to client when data are available from one of the two sides of connection, but it never succeeds.

Here's the code that should forward data from both sides of connection:

```
void proxyHTTPS(int new_sockfd_client, int sockfd_server) {

printf("starting proxyHTTPS\n");
fd_set fdset;
int maxp1 = sockfd_server > new_sockfd_client ? sockfd_server+1 : new_sockfd_client+1;
int r;
int read_from_client = 0;
int read_from_server = 0;
int send_to_client = 0;
int send_to_server = 0;
struct timeval timeout;
char https_buf[4096];
int https_buf_size = sizeof(https_buf);
memset(https_buf, 0, https_buf_size);
// tried 0, 5, 10, 20, 30, 60 seconds timeout,
// still got this problem
timeout.tv_sec = 10;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;

while (true) {
    FD_ZERO(&fdset);
    FD_SET(new_sockfd_client, &fdset);
    FD_SET(sockfd_server, &fdset);
    timeout.tv_sec = 10;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    r = select(maxp1, &fdset, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

    if (r < 0) {
        perror("select()");
        break;
    }

    if (r == 0) { // select timed out
        debug_yellow("proxyHTTPS: select() request timeout 408\n");
        break;
    }

    if ((!FD_ISSET(new_sockfd_client, &fdset)) && ((!FD_ISSET(sockfd_server, &fdset)))) {
        debug_red("proxyHTTPS: SELECT sockfds not responding\n");
        break;
    }

    else if (FD_ISSET(new_sockfd_client, &fdset)) {
        debug_green("proxyHTTPS: reading from client and sending to server\n");
        read_from_client = recv(new_sockfd_client, https_buf, https_buf_size, 0);
        if (read_from_client < 0) {
            debug_red("proxyHTTPS recv() from client " << strerror(errno) << '\n');
            break;
        }
        else if (read_from_client == 0) {
            debug_yellow("proxyHTTPS client closed conn\n");
            break;
        }
        else { // read_from_client > 0
            send_to_server = send(sockfd_server, https_buf, read_from_client, 0);
            if (send_to_server > 0) {
                debug_green("proxyHTTPS: sent to server " << std::to_string(send_to_server) << " bytes \n");
            }
            else if (send_to_server == 0) {
                debug_yellow("proxyHTTPS: sent to server 0 bytes...\n");
                break;
            }
            else {
                debug_red("proxyHTTPS send() to server " << strerror(errno) << '\n');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (FD_ISSET(sockfd_server, &fdset)) {
        debug_green("proxyHTTPS: reading from server and sending to client\n");
        read_from_server = recv(sockfd_server, https_buf, https_buf_size, 0);
        if (read_from_server < 0) {
            debug_red("proxyHTTPS recv() from server " << strerror(errno) << '\n');
            break;
        }
        else if (read_from_server == 0) {
            debug_yellow("proxyHTTPS server closed conn\n");
            break;
        }
        else { // read_from_server > 0
            send_to_client = send(new_sockfd_client, https_buf, read_from_server, 0);       
            if (send_to_client > 0) {
                debug_green("proxyHTTPS: sent to client " << std::to_string(send_to_client) << " bytes\n");
            }
            else if (send_to_client == 0) {
                debug_yellow("proxyHTTPS: sent 0 bytes to client, errno: " << errno << '\n');
                break;
            }
            else {
                debug_red("proxyHTTPS send() to client " << strerror(errno) << '\n');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
debug_yellow("proxyHTTPS: quitting\n");
}
```

This is, e.g., a `CONNECT` request the proxy gets from client:

```
CONNECT www.youtube.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.youtube.com:443
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
/r/n
```

If client sends `CONNECT www.netflix.com:443 HTTP/1.1`, my proxy fails and on terminal prints:

```
setting non block socket
connected immediately
setting block socket
54.228.227.144:443 OK
CONNECT: send to client HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
starting proxyHTTPS
proxyHTTPS: reading from server and sending to client
proxyHTTPS read from server: Connection refused
quitting proxyHTTPS
```

If clients sends `CONNECT www.youtube.com:443 HTTP/1.1`, my proxy fails again and shows:

```
setting non block socket
connected immediately
setting block socket
216.58.201.238:443 OK
CONNECT: send to client HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
starting proxyHTTPS
select(): Operation now in progress
proxyHTTPS: select() request timeout 408
quitting proxyHTTPS
```

I think I did all the steps I was told to do in order to establish a tunnel between client and server, `connect()` is always ok, so mistakes must be in my `proxyHTTPS`. I have no clue!

**EDIT 1**: removed `perror()` when `select()` returns 0, since `errno` is not raised; improved error checking in `select()` loop, distinguishing returned values `>` or `==` zero.
Despite that, still got the same problem: in a way or another, can't read any data from client or server.

**EDIT 2**: updated code about connecting to remote server.

I'm starting to think that since the `select()` loop seems correct, the problem may be caused by something else...

Debug functions used above are defined below:

```
#define DEFAULTCOLOR    "\033[0m"
#define RED             "\033[22;31m"
#define YELLOW          "\033[1;33m"
#define GREEN           "\033[0;0;32m"

#define debug_red(...) std::cout << RED << __VA_ARGS__ << DEFAULTCOLOR; fflush(stdout);
#define debug_yellow(...) std::cout << YELLOW << __VA_ARGS__ << DEFAULTCOLOR; fflush(stdout);
#define debug_green(...) std::cout << GREEN << __VA_ARGS__ << DEFAULTCOLOR; fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: btw, your `recv()` in the first output likely returned 0, which technically doesn't set `errno`, hence the `ECONNREFUSED`. Secondly, have you tried actually sending any data from the client to server?

Comment: Also note that the client can send negotiation data immediately after `CONNECT`, as part of the payload. You should be prepared to handle that after the initial `connect()` and not assume that the client will only send you data once you reply with `Connection Established`

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question about "sending any data from the client to server": you mean sending data after sending 200 OK to client after successfull connect, but before calling my `proxyHTTPS`?
I tried to receive something from client with a `recv` so is all blocked until something arrives, but client sends me nothing.
Plus, I can't tell from TLS handshaking data from "normal" data, since I got nothing to my proxy...

Comment: I mean, in your prior calls to `recv()` which isn't shown in the example, are you ensuring you exhaust the _entire_ buffer? i.e. are you sure the client is _only_ sending `CONNECT host.com:443 HTTP/1.1\r\n`? that's actually against the HTTP spec btw, which demands that the `Host` header be included as well. What I mean is that you might have discarded previous data while parsing the initial connect. I can't see your code so I can't tell for sure

Comment: You are right, the `CONNECT` request I posted is incomplete, but only for sake of brevity, since the question was already long. I'll edit the answer including a sample of `CONNECT` request the proxy gets from client.

Comment: Also, you should be sending _two_ `CRLF` sequences, i.e. `HTTP/1.1 Connection Established\r\n\r\n`

Comment: Changed the response to client to `HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n`: yet, same errors as before (connection refused when reading from server for Netflix, and always timed out for Youtube).
I came across this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495938/how-do-i-respond-to-a-connect-method-request-in-a-proxy-server-using-socket-in, may it be of any help?

Comment: I don't see the point of doing the connect in non-blocking mode if you're only going to spin in `select()` until it completes. `recv()' returning zero means the peer has disconnected, not that it sent zero bytes: it can't do that.

Comment: Do you mean the `connect()` at point 3? I didn't include the code, but at point 3 I do: 
`conn_res = connect(sockfd_server, (struct sockaddr *)&remote_server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));`, followed by looping `select()` in point 4.

Comment: There's only one connect here. Everything you've mentioned only amounts to a blocking mode connect plus a custom timeout. Do you really need the custom timeout?

Comment: You don't need to bind an outbound socket, and you still haven't explained why you're doing the connect the hard way. You're using a zero `select()` timeout, which is just a pointless spin loop. You should use a simple blocking mode `connect()`.

Comment: What if I wanted to listen to multiple clients, dealing multiple HTTP requests and therefore opening more than one connection to multiple servers?

Comment: In what measures my question is different from this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495938/how-do-i-respond-to-a-connect-method-request-in-a-proxy-server-using-socket-in?lq=1